# Get Jquery object data by column name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to search ProductName from my JsonObject. 
I tried with (JSON.parse(MyHtml)).ProductName and it worked fine. But I want ProductName or other column names to be pulled dynamically through parameters for a function.

I tried the below attempts but it did not work. what is the issue

```
strSearchByColumn = ProductName
(JSON.parse(MyHtml)).strSearchByColumn

strSearchByColumn = ProductName
(JSON.parse(MyHtml))+'.'+strSearchByColumn

strSearchByColumn = ProductName
(JSON.parse(MyHtml)).+strSearchByColumn
```

Comment: Use bracket notation `JSON.parse(MyHtml)[strSearchByColumn]`

Comment: can you post your json object contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**Bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
 JSON.parse(MyHtml)[strSearchByColumn]
```